# Yocto sato image is running extremely slow, is there a way to improve its performance?

Tags: linux, intel, yocto

We have a legacy device with following configurations:

- Chipset Architecture : Intel NM10 express
- OS : Yocto warrior
- CPU : Atom D2250 Dual Core
- Volatile Memory : 2GB DDR3
- CPU core : 4

After installing yocto sato image on device, we are seeing sluggish behavior. We are unsure whether it is because of hardware limitations or anything else.

If this slow behavior is because of yocto sato image then,

> Is there something which can be done to improve performance?

Additional information:

Output(only first core) of `cat /proc/cpuinfo`:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 54
model name  : Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU D2550   @ 1.86GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x10d
cpu MHz     : 1861.758
cache size  : 512 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug    : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm movbe lahf_lm dtherm arat
bugs        :
bogomips    : 3723.54
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Output of `cat /proc/meminfo`:

```
MemTotal:         917184 kB
MemFree:          700044 kB
MemAvailable:     761264 kB
Buffers:            5928 kB
Cached:            74112 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           129856 kB
Inactive:          44956 kB
Active(anon):      95096 kB
Inactive(anon):     5720 kB
Active(file):      34760 kB
Inactive(file):    39236 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
HighTotal:        102980 kB
HighFree:            220 kB
LowTotal:         814204 kB
LowFree:          699824 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                16 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         94816 kB
Mapped:            42624 kB
Shmem:              6048 kB
Slab:              17692 kB
SReclaimable:       9124 kB
SUnreclaim:         8568 kB
KernelStack:         976 kB
PageTables:         1676 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:      458592 kB
Committed_AS:     348404 kB
VmallocTotal:     122880 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:              528 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:       22520 kB
DirectMap2M:      884736 kB
```

Output of `cat /proc/uptime`:

```
 00:44:08 up 29 min,  load average: 0.51, 0.78, 0.67
```

**Edit1** : lubuntu is running as expected i.e. No sluggish behavior is seen on device

**Edit2** : Graphics gets faster after removing `libglamoregl.so`. What is there in this library which is causing graphics performance issue.

Comment: Performance on what workload?  And slow compared to what?  In-order Atom is not exactly a fast CPU, much slower clock for clock than a Skylake (and it doesn't have turbo, I don't think).  Also memory bandwidth is probably significantly lower than a modern desktop/laptop.

Comment: does the system have GPU and if yes is it enabled?

Comment: @PeterCordes slow behavior on no extra workload. Please watch this clip https://youtu.be/bgiRWUBaDCc

Comment: @Khem `lspci` shows `Intel Corporation Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx Integrated Graphics Controller`

Comment: Oh, so slow behaviour on actually drawing the screen, i.e. the workload is graphics.  You didn't say that before.  Make sure desktop compositing is disabled; it probably has slow OpenGL so you don't want your GUI to run your 2D desktop as if it were 3D graphics.  And other than that, check your Xorg.conf, or look for options for that X11 graphics driver you can tweak.

Comment: @PeterCordes Graphics gets faster after removing `libglamoregl.so`. What is there in this library which is causing graphics performance issue.

Comment: Probably it's more like without that library, something uses a fallback to some other way of drawing, other than OpenGL.  Maybe you could get the same thing by disabling compositing of your desktop like I suggested earlier so it doesn't try to use 3D.  Or maybe not, IDK.  `glamor` is an OpenGL helper library, IIRC.

Comment: `Is it okay to have it disabled on final product?` Please give your views on this.. From web, GLAMOR is a translation layer that converts 2D graphics operations to 3D graphics operations This makes sense when 3D GPU acceleration is available, but when using a simple unaccelerated 2D GPU like the AST VGA GPU, the result is that 2D operations get converted to 3D operations by GLAMOR and are then converted back to 2D by llvmpipe, which introduces significant overhead.